# Why Am I Getting A Typescript Error In This Function Code?

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error when compiling my .NET Core MVC solution in Visual studio 2017. I am not sure this error even affects anything or is being correctly reported.

Error:
`TS2322 Build:Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(result: any) => void'`

Code:

```
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params: Params, updateCallback?: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR {
            if (!updateCallback && typeof params == "function") {
                updateCallback = params;
                params = undefined;
            }
            const x = getCached(url, params);
            const cached = x.cached;
            var request = x.request();
            if (updateCallback) {
                if (cached) updateCallback(cached);
                request.done(function (result) {
                    // Data has changed?
                    if (cached !== result && JSON.stringify(cached) !== JSON.stringify(result))
                        updateCallback(result);
                });
            }

            return request;
        }
```

Line with the error:
`updateCallback = params;`

Params definition:
`type Params = { [key: string]: any };`

What have I tried?
If I change the line with the error to:
`updateCallback = function (data) { };` then there  is no Typescript error so I guess that `updateCallback` needs to be assigned to a function with one argument and no return value and type `Params` doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Function` is the most general you can type a function. It is too broad to be used where a more specific one (`(result: any) => void` function from `any` to `void`) is expected. This is what the actual error is saying but the more interesting answer is why you have it in the first place.

There is a javascript convention hidden in here with the function signature. It is really overloaded like the following:

```js
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, updateCallback: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR;
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params: Params): JQueryXHR;
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params: Params, updateCallback: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR;
```

If only 2 parameters are given, the second could be the `updateCallback` or `params`. If 3 are given, the second is the `params` and 3rd is the `updateCallback`.

Since javascript doesn't support type overloaded functions, it has to be handled manually. Hence we define a function with a type that *satisfies all 3 signatures*. A more appropriate one would be the following:

```js
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params?: Params, updateCallback?: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR
```

Then provide the logic to decide which signature we are actually calling. This is where the `typeof params == "function"` comes from.

```js
// If updateCallback is not defined we have one of the first 2 signatures.
// If params is a function then it must be the 2nd signature. Update local vars to reflect that.
if (!updateCallback && typeof params == "function") {
    updateCallback = params; // The 2nd parameter is actuall the callback
    params = undefined; // The params were not actually given.
}
```

Since for this case it is not worth trying to get typescript to "check your work". We need to opt for a "trust me, I know what I'm doing" with a cast `as (a: any) => void`.

```js
if (!updateCallback && typeof params == "function") {
    updateCallback = params as (a: any) => void;
    params = undefined;
}
```

Here is the whole thing. Went a bit overboard with the signatures for the sake of explanation be there they are

```js
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, updateCallback: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR;
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params: Params): JQueryXHR;
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params: Params, updateCallback: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR;
export function getCachedThenUpdate(url: string, params?: Params, updateCallback?: (result: any) => void): JQueryXHR {
    if (!updateCallback && typeof params == "function") {
        updateCallback = params as (a: any) => void;
        params = undefined;
    }
    const x = getCached(url, params);
    const cached = x.cached;
    var request = x.request();
    if (updateCallback) {
        if (cached) updateCallback(cached);
        request.done(function (result) {
            // Data has changed?
            if (cached !== result && JSON.stringify(cached) !== JSON.stringify(result))
                updateCallback(result);
        });
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: If 2 parameters are passed, how could they be url and updateCallback when the params parameter is not marked optional?

Comment: When you overload a signature, the caller get's to pick one. The 4th one is not really visible. So there are 3 valid signatures, the first of which is the `url` and `updateCallback` one. In that signature `params` is not even present. The only way to know the caller has chosen that signature is if the 3rd parameter is not present and the 2nd is a function. The original question provides a bad signature for the function with that body. Does that help/answer your question? If so I'll update the answer.